# Find: who write backups

Tags: backup, daemon

I have some daemon which writes Mongo and MySQL backups to the directory `/opt/BACKUP`, but I don't know - what kind of daemon, when it works and where I can find its settings?

These files are in the directory:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root 10954766682 Aug 30 21:02 history_2013-08-26.sql.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root 22707064861 Sep 19 07:07 history.sql
drwx------ 2 root  root       16384 Dec 24  2012 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root        4096 Sep 19 03:12 mongodb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  6708923175 Sep 18 04:16 mongodb.0.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  6685715560 Sep 17 04:16 mongodb.1.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  6733542547 Sep 19 04:17 mongodb.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 5 mysql root        4096 Sep 19 06:25 mysql
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root        4096 Dec 24  2012 nobacula
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root        4096 Aug 29 04:05 tmp
```

How I can find who writes mongodb.* and history_2013-08-26.sql.bz2?

Comment: Check your crontabs: /etc/cron.d or /etc/cron.daily. In some of them you'll probably find something related to mongoDB. The utility should be 'mongodump', and the configuration, if not in /etc, is at command line level.

Comment: If you can catch it in the act, `lsof filename` should give you the process that is writing to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot find out directly. The only information you have is the *owner* and the timestamps of the files.

#### owner

since the files in question are owned by `root`, this gives you little information.

#### timestamps - mongodb

As you can see, the `mongodb` backups basically all happen at the same time (quarter past 4 in the morning). This - and the fact that the creation time is somewhen at night, when services are most likely under little load) makes it very likely that the backup is triggered by a `cron` process; therefore you need to check the cron-configuration.

- `/etc/crontab` (unlikely, since this is usually controlled by the system)
- `/etc/cron.daily/` (might be, depending on your settings; on my Debian/jessie system, *cron.daily* jobs are run at 6:25 in the morning according to `/etc/crontag`, thus unlikely as well)
- `/etc/cron.d/` (most likely)
- the *root*-user's crontab file (e.g. `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` but best accessed by running `crontab -l` as *root* or `sudo crontab -l -u root`.)

#### timestamps - mysql

The `history.sql` file is pretty recent (Sept.19), and has been created pretty early (`7:07`); it might as well have been created by a cron-job (see above)

The `history_2013-08-26.sql.bz2` has been created on *Aug.30 at 21:02*; assuming that 9pm is a time when sysadmins might be expected to do some work and noting that there is a discrepancy between timestamp (Aug.30) and file-name (Aug.26), I'd assume that this file has been created *manually*.

Comment: Thank you! The demon was found in the folder /etc/cron.daily

Comment: btw, a process started periodically by cron is not strictly-speaking a "daemon" (a deamon is continuously running)

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to know who wrote a file but they usually require setting up a watch beforehand.

Since all files were created at about the same time, look for daily cron jobs that run about that time. This has a good chance of giving you the answer.

If you have [BSD process accounting](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/html_mono/accounting.html) enabled, run `lastcomm` to see what processes might have been running at the time the file was written. It can be difficult, since process accounting only keeps track of when a process was started, not when it finished running.

There are ways to find out who's responsible the next time a file is created. One possibility is with the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/):

```
auditctl -A exit,always -F path=/opt/BACKUP/mongodb.tgz -S open -S rename
```

Another possibility is with [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). For example, set up an [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) job:

```
/opt/BACKUP/mongodb.tgz IN_MOVED_TO,IN_CREATE logger $% $@/$#
```